# Orchard - Need To Enable Lucene?

Tags: lucene, indexing, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have an installation of Orchard 1.8 setup that has a message at the top of the admin area which says "You need to enable an index implementation module like Lucene." The confusing part here is Lucene is already installed/enabled according to the admin area so I'm a little lost. I don't have any indexes in App_Data/Sites/Default to remove (implying nothing is corrupt), nor is the option to create an index available.

I've tried disabling/re-enabling Lucene and the search functions, to no avail. Any guesses?

Answer (score 1):

Go to /Admin/Indexing and create an index.

Comment: Can't - inside Admin/Indexing it says "There is currently no index":, but there isn't a Create option like normal. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Make sure that you have Search and Indexing enabled, in addition to Lucene. Also check app_data\logs.

Comment: All three are enabled (and I've tried disabling/re-enabling them with no luck). I'm not sure what I'm looking for in the logs, but there isn't any mention of Lucene, Search or Indexing in them.

Comment: We're looking for any exception happening when you hit the /Admin/Indexing page. Another thing you can try is to attach a debugger and break on exceptions.

Comment: Ah. No exceptions found in the logs unfortunately. This is in a shared hosting environment so what's the best way to attach a debugger? Download the site (it's the compiled version, not the source version) and setup IIS on my box and attach VS to that process?